# HTML DropDownList and ActionLink on same line

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to display a `DropDownList` and a Link next to it, using *MCV5* and *Bootwatch (CSS)*

View:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="productoID">Producto</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.productoID, null, "-- Seleccione un Producto --", new { @id = "producto", @Selected = false, @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.productoID)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.ActionLink("+", "../Producto/Create")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`
```

Actually they are displayed on same line, **but not next to each other**, there is an space I **cannot** remove.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get rid of the space because you are putting the dropdown list and the anchor in separate columns.

You want to put them in the same column using an [inline form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline).

Comment: Remove Rows, add inline form, both controls are displayed on same line, but DropDownList are no longer same size as all other controls.